Simultaneous upload creating conflicting files when Multiple People using macroenabled workbook update to a same dropbox shared folder
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objFile As Object
Dim objConnection, objRecordset As Object
Dim LastLocalChange, LastDbUpdate As Date
Dim DbFile, ConnString As String


Sub SyncToDatabase()
DbFile = Sheet1.Range("Q4").Value 'Customer Database Location
LastLocalChange = Sheet1.Range("Q6 ").Value
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(DbFile)
If objFile.DateLastModified < LastLocalChange Then 'Local Change was made, update Database
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Kill (DbFile) 'Delete the current database version
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs DbFile, FileFormat:=51
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    
End If
End Sub


Sub SyncFromDatabase()

LastLocalChange = Sheet1.Range("Q6").Value
DbFile = Sheet1.Range("Q4").Value 'Customer Database Location
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(DbFile)
If objFile.DateLastModified > LastLocalChange Then 'Database Change was made, update Local Database
'Check Last Database Update
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & Sheet1.Range("Q4").Value & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0"";"
objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM[Data$]", objConnection
With Worksheets("Data")
.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset
End With

objRecordset.Close
objConnection.Close
End If
End Sub

I'm using the above macros to create a database excel file.
I got this code from this youtube video >
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WI-uhkrnk2I&list=WL&index=80&t=1555s
I am not using his entire format. The macro enabled workbook I'm using is different. I'm only using the above macros from his workbook.
Sync from database macro is working as expected. It simply copies the file from dropbox location.
The issue happens after "synctodatabase" if 2 different people simultaneously update the file , it creates a conflicting file as the condition ( locale time vs folder time ) is satisfied in "sync to database" macro.
I've assigned macros to my existing macros and they work perfectly.
I've attached photos of my form.

"Submit" and "update" (see the attached images)  are done by 2 different persons.
Issue happens when both work simultaneously.
PS (I've not coded the macros. I've compiled macros available on the net and mostly googled how they work and edited them according to my needs. most of them (in my Form) achieve simple things like copying data finding it etc. I do not know how to make a new macro from scratch)
Is there a better way to do this syncing?

This is not a good model for this kind of process.  The challenges you're going to face are pretty substantial.  Over writing other user's changes is going to cause some serious data integrity issues.

I figured after trying to make it work. I've been suggested databases but as of right now im stuck with excel. Thanks though
